# prepositional pattern with choice of prepositions ("to" vs. "for")

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositional-phrases

Now I am learning about prepositional patterns, but I have questions about when to use proper prepositions.

Here's question sentences

1. I gave a book **to** John.
2. I gave a book **for** John.
3. He brought a chair *to* her.
4. He brought a chair *for* her.
5. send a letter *to* Steve.
6. send a letter *for* Steve. (wrong)

in these two sentences, my teacher told me that *to John* in sentence 1 means *goal*, whereas *for John* in sentence 2 refers to *Benefactive* or *proxy*.

sentence 1 and 2 seems okay to me, however, sentences 3 and 4 confused me.

I think meaning of sentence 3 and sentence 4 which interpreted as *Benefactive* are same.. 
I don't get difference of underlying meaning.

Also, I don't know the reason why my teacher just said sentence 6 is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are tricky. Each preposition typically has several meanings (sometimes more than a dozen), and the meaning often changes depending on the verb.

> 1) I gave a book **to** John.
>   2) I gave a book **for** John.
>   2a) I bought a book **for** John.

If the verb were *bought* instead of *give*, the second sentence would work. However, the expression *gave something for someone* sounds awkward. I wouldn't use #2 unless, say, John couldn't make it to a baby shower, and I gave the mother-to-be a book, saying the book was from John instead of from me. When dealing with gift-giving, we typically ***buy*** something **for** someone, and we ***give*** something **to** someone.

> 3) He brought a chair **to** her.
>   4) He brought a chair **for** her.

Both of these are fine, and mean pretty much the same thing. The first emphasizes the **action**; the other emphasizes the **intent**. The version with *to* could be further explained as: *He brought a chair **to where she was standing***, while the version with *for* could be paraphrased as: *He brought a chair **for her to sit in***. Put another way, the first tells us *where* he brought the chair, the second tells us *why* he brought the chair.

> 5) I sent a letter **to** Steve.
>   6) I sent a letter **for** Steve.

Sentence #5 is a normal, idiomatic way to explain that Steve's name and address were on the envelope, and we mailed the letter to him. Sentence #6 is more unusual, but it isn't incorrect. Let's say Steve and I are roommates, and he wrote a letter to his mom last night. He wants to send this letter today, but the post office is five miles in the wrong direction during his daily commute – yet he knows I drive right by the post office on my way to work. He asks, "Would you mail this for me this morning?" Naturally, I agree. When I get to work later that day, a co-worker might say, "As I was driving into work, I thought I saw you getting out of your car at the post office," and I might answer, "Yes, I was sending a letter for my roommate Steve," meaning I was doing him a favor.

This isn't the only interpretation for Sentence #6. We might say:

> We sent a card for Steve.

meaning that we mailed a card for Steve to receive. (Perhaps Steve is in the hospital recovering from surgery, and we sent him a get-well-soon card.) Much like the chair example discussed earlier, using *to* emphasizes **where** the card was mailed (to Steve), while using *for* emphasizes **why** the card was sent (to cheer him up). The version with *for* may sound a little awkward by itself, but, with the right surrounding context, it could work. We need to be careful when we say something is "wrong." *Wrong* doesn't always mean grammatically wrong, sometimes it just means *not idiomatic*, or *unusual*, or *it doesn't mean what you are trying to say*.

Comment: Thank you so much! thus I can conclude(of course considering the context is most important,) that I should use 'to' when I want to express the direction or action, while put 'for' when there is any intent to do action?

Comment: @Belle - That's a decent generalization, but no, you can't conclude that as a hard-and-fast rule. Prepositions are very elastic, which is why dictionaries list so many meanings for such little words. Consider the delivery clerk: "I have a package **for** David" – I don't think that's exactly "intent." Or consider the race car driver: "We pushed the car **to** its limit" – that's not really "direction." The only thing you should conclude is that there is no simple rule that can always reliably tell you when to use _to_ instead of _for_ – it depends on the verb and on the context.